# django-filter and ForeignKeys

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, django-filter

Is there a way to use django-filter with the Foreignkey? For example:

**models.py**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    location = models.Charfield(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)


class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.Charfield(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    last_name = models.Charfield(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    age = models.Integerfield()
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**filters.py**

```
class PersonFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = [
        'first_name ',
        'last_name ',
        'company ',
    ]
```

Right now, I only know how to filter for the whole company and often thats's totally fine, but is there a way to - for example - filter for the 'loaction' or any other values as long it's connected with ForeignKey?
And if it's not, is there a better solution than django-filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Same as in Django, use the django `__` relationship syntax.

```
class PersonFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = [
        'first_name ',
        'last_name ',
        'company',
        'company__location',
    ]
```

Comment: Such a great solution! Thank you very much!